Alternative to "pluck" for a single record
In Ruby on Rails, the array method pluck works either if the things are objects or hashes. E.g.
array_of_hashes = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 25 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 30 },
  { name: "Charlie", age: 35 }
]

array_of_hashes.pluck :name
=> ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]

This also works:
array_of_objects = People.last(3).to_a

array_of_objects.pluck(:name)
=> ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"]

Is there an alternative to pluck but for a single thing that can be either an object or a hash and it will either invoke it as a method or access the hash key like pluck does for each object?
object_or_hash.foobar(:name) 
=> "Alice"

What I'm really trying to do it refactor this so I can avoid the if:
if answer_attributes.is_a?(Hash)
  AnswerParams.new(
    question: answer_attributes[:question],
    options: answer_attributes[:options],
    answer: answer_attributes[:answer]
  )
else
  AnswerParams.new(
    question: answer_attributes.question,
    options: answer_attributes.options,
    answer: answer_attributes.answer
  )
end


I think you might be confused on how Enumerable#pluckactually works.
array_of_hashes and array_of_objects only works because both Hash and AR objects respond to #[].
Enumerable#pluck does not actually call the method by name directly instead it simply iterates over the collection calling #[] with each desired key.
Given this and your examples the conditional is unnecessary when you can just use the #[] method.
e.g.
 AnswerParams.new(
    question: answer_attributes[:question],
    options: answer_attributes[:options],
    answer: answer_attributes[:answer]
  )

Additionally both objects also respond to slice so the above can be simplified to
AnswerParams.new(**answer_attributes.slice(:question, :options, :answer).symbolize_keys)

If you truly need this functionality for a custom object, and would like it to remain consistent with the other objects described, you can do so by simply adding the #[] method to your object.
Even something as simple as this should suffice:
def [](value) 
  begin
    public_send(value) 
  rescue NoMethodError 
    nil
  end 
end 


I think you'd need to create your own custom method. Here's an idea based off your existing code that would at least eliminate the if:
def fetch_value(x, key)
  if x.is_a?(Hash)
    x[key]
  else
    x.send(key)
  end
end

AnswerParams.new(
  question: fetch_value(answer_attributes, :question),
  options: fetch_value(answer_attributes, :options),
  answer: fetch_value(answer_attributes, :answer)
)


It's never going to be as concise as you might hope, but my approach would be for the AnswerParams class to accept in its initializer either an object or a hash. Converting hashes to OpenStruct instances means you can treat them like objects.
class AnswerParams # does it inherit from ActiveRecord?
  attr_accessor :question, :options, :answer

  def initialize(object_or_hash)
    object = object_or_hash.is_a?(Hash) : OpenStruct.new(object_or_hash) : object_or_hash
    @question = object.question
    @options = object.options
    @answer = object.answer
  end
end

